# Delphi7: TBitmap.Canvas.Handle = 0

Tags: delphi, handle

I am facing this problem for a long time, and have not found anything that could help me solve it.
I use a TBitmap to receive data coming from a camera (stream) and then save the image to disk. 
Sometimes an exception occurs. After several tests I found the flaw: The handle property of the TBitmap's Canvas with value 0. To bypass this problem, when I detect this value 0 in the handle, restart the application (destroy and recreate the TBitmap did not work), but sometimes this error occurs frequently. Has anyone had a problem like this? What could I be doing wrong? Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there's a bug in your code. Does all bitmap access happen in the same thread?

Comment: No it isn't, but it's protected by critical section in all cross-thread access.

Comment: Is that enough. Don't you need to use `Lock`. I must say I am surprised that you neglected to mention the threading aspect of your code.

Comment: OK, sorry for this...But i already tried lock on canvas and the result is the same.

Comment: I think you need to cut the program down to something small that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score -1):

TBitmap internally uses a TBitmapCanvas wrapper object for TBitmap.Canvas. If you have access to the source (Graphics.pas) you should have a look. Chances are one or more WinAPI GDI calls don't handle the return value in case of an error. Some GDI calls have a very slim chance of failing, so it's somewhat of a gamble to leave out checking each and every returned value to gain a bit of performance, but in cases of high load these may be the first indicators that things will go wrong anyway.

I suggest you try use the debug DCU's to step through your program using TBitmap.Canvas, list the GDI calls that are used to make things work, then code these operations checking the returned values and handling any errors correctly. This should enable you to find out more what is going on when the connection to the camera is failing, and probably will decrease some of the overhead you have from using TBitmap.